# What options other than editing pixels do we have for image color editing in WPF and Windows Store Apps?

Tags: wpf, windows-store-apps

To edit the colors of an image in WPF and Windows Store Apps I know that we can read the pixels of an image, edit them and write them to an new BitmapSource or WriteableBitmap. I doubt that this technique is always best. What other options do we have to edit the colors of an image, let's say to change the brightness or gamma?

Comment: If you don't want to edit the pixels, what do you want to change? All information in pixel based images is contained in the pixels.

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Reading, modifying and writing pixels back one pixel at a time will likely perform badly compared to direct mathematical operations on the underlying bitmap buffer of the image.

Comment: @MartinLiversage: Agreed. But that's still editing the pixels...

Comment: @DanielHilgarth: Sure I want to edit the pixels. The question was more how to do that. In GDI we can use ColorMatrix. I heard about pixel shader effects that could be used as well. I was just wondering if editing reading the pixels and writing them back is a good solution for certain kinds of image editing. But as it seems I could change the buffer of a WriteableBitmap directly (did not try that yet).

Comment: @JürgenBayer: So your question is: "How to apply an arbitrary  transformation to an image in a performant manner?"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get access to the underlying bitmap buffer which allows you to manipulate the pixels efficiently. In WPF you can use the [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.imaging.writeablebitmap%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class:

> For greater control over updates, and for multi-threaded access to the back buffer, use the following workflow.
>
> 1. Call the Lock method to reserve the back buffer for updates.
> 2. Obtain a pointer to the back buffer by accessing the BackBuffer property.
> 3. Write changes to the back buffer. Other threads may write changes to the back buffer when the WriteableBitmap is locked.
> 4. Call the AddDirtyRect method to indicate areas that have changed.
> 5. Call the Unlock method to release the back buffer and allow presentation to the screen.
>
> When updates are sent to the rendering thread, the rendering thread copies the changed rectangles from the back buffer to the front buffer. The rendering system controls this exchange to avoid deadlocks and redraw artifacts, such as "tearing".

In Windows Store apps you can use the [`WriteableBitmap`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br243259.aspx) class:

> **PixelBuffer** cannot be written to directly, however, you can use language-specific techniques to access the buffer and change its contents.
>
> - To access the pixel content from C# or Microsoft Visual Basic, you can use the **AsStream** extension method to access the underlying buffer as a stream.
> - To access the pixel content from C++, you can query for the **IBufferByteAccess** type (defined in Robuffer.h) and directly access its **Buffer** property.

Comment: Thanks. WriteableBitmap was already mentioned in my question. Windows Store Apps allow reading the pixels using a BitmapDecoder as well.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood. You meant accessing the buffer and changing the pixels directly I suppose.